# Cycle of length $n$ in simple graph with at least $2n$ vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

I solved the following exercise: Consider a simple graph $G$ on $\geq 6$ vertices and let $G^c$ be the graph with the same vertex set, with $uv$ being an edge of $G^c$ if-f is not an edge of $G$. Prove that a) either $G$ or $G^c$ has a vertex of degree at least $3$, and that b) either $G$ or $G^c$ contains a cycle of length $3$.

I solved the first part by the pigeonhole principle and in the same vein we can show that, if $G$ is simple graph in $2n$ vertices, thein either $G$ or $G^c$ (as defined above) contains a vertex $v$ of degree $\geq n$. The second part was solved by considering adjacencies between the $3$ vertices that are neighbours of the aforementioned $v$ in either $G$ or $G^c$, but I managed to solve it mainly because there were few vertices so I could draw a sketch and consider all possible cases, and it made me wonder: If $G$ is a simple graph in $2n$ vertices, is it true that either $G$ or $G^c$ contain a cycle of length $n$, and if so, how would that proof go? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, when $n>3$, $2n-1$ vertices are enough. This is Theorem 2 in the paper [Ramsey Numbers for Cycles in Graphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0095-8956(73)80005-X) by Bondy and Erdös.

For odd values of $n$, the example of the complete bipartite graph $K_{n-1,n-1}$ shows that $2n-2$ vertices are not enough.

When $n=4$, $6$ vertices are required; in the paper [All Ramsey Numbers for Cycles in Graphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(74)90151-4) by Faudree and Schelp, it is shown that when $n > 4$ and $n$ is even, $\frac32n - 1$ is the minimum number of vertices. (For example, $\frac32 \cdot 6 - 1 = 8$ vertices guarantee that either $G$ or $G^c$ will contain a $6$-cycle.) This second paper also solves all the asymmetric cases, when we want a cycle of length $r$ in $G$ or a cycle of length $s$ in $G^c$.