# Complete graph in $n$ vertices in simple graph with at least $2n$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

As a follow-up to this question, [Cycle of length $n$ in simple graph with at least $2n$ vertices.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165160/cycle-of-length-n-in-simple-graph-with-at-least-2n-vertices)
, I wondered the following:
Consider a simple graph $G$ on $2n$ vertices and let $G^c$ be the graph with the same vertex set, with $uv$ being an edge of $G^c$ if-f is not an edge of $G$. Is it true that either $G$ or $G^c$ contain a copy of the complete graph in $n$ vertices? I checked the case for $6$ vertices, where either $G$ or $G^c$ contain a complete graph in $3$ vertices (a cycle of length $3$), but are $2n$ vertices always enough for either $G$ or $G^c$ to contain a complete graph in $n$ vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what [Ramsey Numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamseyNumber.html) describe. What you conjecture is that $R(n,n) \leq 2n$ which is not true. For example, $R(4,4) = 18$. In general, Ramsey numbers get really big so this bound is unlikely to hold for more than just a few values of $n$ (possibly only for $n=3$).

Comment: I see, thanks for the reference!